# Prove or disprove: The series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function such that  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$, And $f(x) > 0$
Prove or disprove:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/f(n)$ Diverges.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Ive been trying for a while but I could not make any progress at all.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try $f(x)=2^x\hspace{0pt}$

Comment: @ElliotG Your $f$ Is not uniformly continuous

Comment: Surely the condition " $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$ " is redundant. Interesting question though.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, Thank you.

Comment: I have found this reference using the very efficient formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/search/